# How to implement secure cookie check in Magento 1.4.1.1 similar to Magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, security, cookie

We have an option for secure cookie check in Magento 1.9.1 as per
[Magento Community Edition 1.9.1 release notes](http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/content/magento/release-notes-ce-1.9.1.html)

- Added a secure cookie flag for the storefront to prevent man-in-the-middle attacks. There is no change to the Secure and Unsecure Web configuration options.

Does this help to overcome this  [OWASP-2010: A3,](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A3) issue?

```
app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Session\Abstract\Varien.php
```

.

```
      if (Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->isSecure() && empty($cookieParams['secure'])) {
        // secure cookie check to prevent MITM attack
        $secureCookieName = $sessionName . '_cid';
        if (isset($_SESSION[self::SECURE_COOKIE_CHECK_KEY])
            && $_SESSION[self::SECURE_COOKIE_CHECK_KEY] !== md5($cookie->get($secureCookieName))
        ) {
            session_regenerate_id(false);
            $sessionHosts = $this->getSessionHosts();
            $currentCookieDomain = $cookie->getDomain();
            foreach (array_keys($sessionHosts) as $host) {
                // Delete cookies with the same name for parent domains
                if (strpos($currentCookieDomain, $host) > 0) {
                    $cookie->delete($this->getSessionName(), null, $host);
                }
            }
            $_SESSION = array();
        }
        if (!isset($_SESSION[self::SECURE_COOKIE_CHECK_KEY])) {
            $checkId = Mage::helper('core')->getRandomString(16);
            $cookie->set($secureCookieName, $checkId, null, null, null, true);
            $_SESSION[self::SECURE_COOKIE_CHECK_KEY] = md5($checkId);
        }
    }
```

How can I implement this feature in lower versions of Magento without upgrading to higher version? Do we have some patch or workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a local copy of Varien.php file at following location

```
app\code\local\Mage\Core\Model\Session\Abstract\Varien.php
```

On top of file add

```
const SECURE_COOKIE_CHECK_KEY = '_secure_cookie_check';
```

Go to  `public function start($sessionName=null)` method and add following lines after `session_start()`

```
if (Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->isSecure() && empty($cookieParams['secure'])) {
// secure cookie check to prevent MITM attack
$secureCookieName = $sessionName . '_cid';
if (isset($_SESSION[self::SECURE_COOKIE_CHECK_KEY])
    && $_SESSION[self::SECURE_COOKIE_CHECK_KEY] !== md5($cookie->get($secureCookieName))
) {
    session_regenerate_id(false);
    $sessionHosts = $this->getSessionHosts();
    $currentCookieDomain = $cookie->getDomain();
    foreach (array_keys($sessionHosts) as $host) {
        // Delete cookies with the same name for parent domains
        if (strpos($currentCookieDomain, $host) > 0) {
            $cookie->delete($this->getSessionName(), null, $host);
        }
    }
    $_SESSION = array();
}
if (!isset($_SESSION[self::SECURE_COOKIE_CHECK_KEY])) {
    $checkId = Mage::helper('core')->getRandomString(16);
    $cookie->set($secureCookieName, $checkId, null, null, null, true);
    $_SESSION[self::SECURE_COOKIE_CHECK_KEY] = md5($checkId);
}
}
```

When ever we move to a secure page it creates a new cookie with sessionname_cid
( `$secureCookieName = $sessionName . '_cid';`)

Comment: Does this will add secure attribute to all magento cookies ?

Comment: No, I think only to customer session cookie.

Comment: Is their any way we can setting up (Secure & HttpOnly) attribute on all cookies ?